# Error when running random_forest_example.py in spark with python

Tags: python, apache-spark

I'm a rookie in Spark so I was going through some examples provided in Spark example folders. When I tried **random_forest_example.py**, I got the following error:

> py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling
>   z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob. :
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
>   Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0
>   in stage 2.0 (TID 3, localhost): java.net.SocketException: Connection
>   reset by peer: socket write error     at
>   java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)   at
>   java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.io.DataOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$3.apply(PythonRDD.scala:251)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1772)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread.run(PythonRDD.scala:208)

The code I was running was:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import sys

from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.ml.classification import RandomForestClassifier
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer
from pyspark.ml.regression import RandomForestRegressor
from pyspark.mllib.evaluation import MulticlassMetrics, RegressionMetrics
from pyspark.mllib.util import MLUtils
from pyspark.sql import Row, SQLContext

"""
A simple example demonstrating a RandomForest Classification/Regression Pipeline.
Run with:
  bin/spark-submit examples/src/main/python/ml/random_forest_example.py
"""


def testClassification(train, test):
    # Train a RandomForest model.
    # Setting featureSubsetStrategy="auto" lets the algorithm choose.
    # Note: Use larger numTrees in practice.

    rf = RandomForestClassifier(labelCol="indexedLabel", numTrees=3, maxDepth=4)

    model = rf.fit(train)
    predictionAndLabels = model.transform(test).select("prediction", "indexedLabel") \
        .map(lambda x: (x.prediction, x.indexedLabel))

    metrics = MulticlassMetrics(predictionAndLabels)
    print("weighted f-measure %.3f" % metrics.weightedFMeasure())
    print("precision %s" % metrics.precision())
    print("recall %s" % metrics.recall())


def testRegression(train, test):
    # Train a RandomForest model.
    # Note: Use larger numTrees in practice.

    rf = RandomForestRegressor(labelCol="indexedLabel", numTrees=3, maxDepth=4)

    model = rf.fit(train)
    predictionAndLabels = model.transform(test).select("prediction", "indexedLabel") \
        .map(lambda x: (x.prediction, x.indexedLabel))

    metrics = RegressionMetrics(predictionAndLabels)
    print("rmse %.3f" % metrics.rootMeanSquaredError)
    print("r2 %.3f" % metrics.r2)
    print("mae %.3f" % metrics.meanAbsoluteError)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        print("Usage: random_forest_example", file=sys.stderr)
        exit(1)
    sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonRandomForestExample")
    sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

    # Load and parse the data file into a dataframe.
    df = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sc, "D:\spark-1.4.0\examples\src\main\python\ml\sample_libsvm_data.txt").toDF()

    # Map labels into an indexed column of labels in [0, numLabels)
    stringIndexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="label", outputCol="indexedLabel")
    si_model = stringIndexer.fit(df)
    td = si_model.transform(df)
    [train, test] = td.randomSplit([0.7, 0.3])
    testClassification(train, test)
    testRegression(train, test)
    sc.stop()
```

I checked line by line and found that the error was generated at this line

```
 df = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sc, "D:\spark1.4.0\examples\src\main\python\ml\sample_libsvm_data.txt").toDF()
```

It seems that something was wrong with the .toDF() method but I don't know what caused it. Could anyone help me solve this.

Comment: Are you sure it is a correct path? Example data is located in `data` not in `examples`.

Comment: @zero323 Thank you for your reply. Yes, I'm sure. The original path didn't work for me so I moved the data file to the location I specified.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running a Spark instance in the background? If not, you should deploy Spark locally in your script (the "setMaster("local")" part in the config), this is from the official Spark documentation:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
conf = (SparkConf()
         .setMaster("local")
         .setAppName("My app")
         .set("spark.executor.memory", "1g"))
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)code here
```